# Which reference to use in the Excel VBA Editor when trying to access Lync via VBA

Tags: vba, excel, lync

I am trying to access Microsoft Lync via VBA out of Excel.

Which reference I have to add to be able to access the Lync-specific objects? I browsed and tried all dll's in the Lync-Folder but none seems to work.

Do I have to install some extra package to be able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>References</kbd> > set checkmark at lines beginning with Microsoft Office Communicator

Comment: The most accepted way of hyperlinking in SO is the way I did it :)

Comment: If it is a  matter of caps, one can change it to lower case. Regarding the link, I just noticed that it is for a chm file so yes it's not good enough. Let me see if there is another link :)